# Assignment from Rust match statement

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Is there an idiom in Rust which is used to assign the value of a variable based on a match clause? I know something like

```
val b = a match {
     case x if x % 2 == 1 => false
     case _ => true
}
```

from Scala and was wondering whether you can do the same in Rust. Is there a way to evaluate a match clause as an expression and return something from it or is it just a statement in Rust?

Comment: Straight from the [Rust Book: 4.14 Match](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/match.html) (2nd example). I advise you read the book (or at least check it when you have a question).

Comment: tbh I find the notion honorable, but the book hardly useful (I actually checked, but checked the pattern matching section, which has no example with an assignment). The book is very hard to search and misses a keyword index. I asked because I got some completely unrelated error message out of the compiler, since I forgot the colon after the first clause, and google returned no useful information.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's hard to search for a specific answer like that as there are so much new things and concepts in rust

Comment: @Fayeure: Indeed; I still recommend reading the book anyway, but fully understand that just because someone's read it doesn't mean they remember every single piece of information nor that they can find it back. I... don't think I do, to be honest ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Rust, nearly every statement is also an expression.

You can do this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 3;
    let b = match a {
        x if x % 2 == 1 => false,
        _ => true,
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ef1ff1ec0462261a4c3c46e2fd484a1d&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 7):

Sure there is:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;

    let b = match a % 2 {
        1 => false,
        _ => true
    };

    assert_eq!(b, false);
}
```

Relevant Rust Reference chapter: [match expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions).

Though in your case a simple `if` would suffice:

```
let b = if a % 2 == 1 { false } else { true };
```

or even

```
let b = a % 2 != 1;
```